# How can ubuntu separate system files and normal files?

Tags: server, lubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-headers, selinux

I'm new to Ubuntu Linux but I have one question. How can Ubuntu separate system files and normal files? I searched for them everywhere and I can't find any of them.

Where does Ubuntu store these files?  What I mean by normal files is, the files that only store data, text, pictures, and others.

Comment: You haven't specifically provided release details, however you've tagged an EOL (*end-of-life*) or ESM release which is now off-topic here (being supported only via Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage). See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   Your tags also are unclear, How does the EOL/ESM release match with Lubuntu, WSL & SELinux?  and how does it relate to files?

Comment: I went ahead and answered it because the answer applies to all versions. However, in the future, it should be noted that 12.04 is EOL and questions for EOL releases are off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System files are all the directories (folders) under `/` (which is often referred to as your "root directory") that are not under `/home/`.

A few examples are `/etc/` and `/usr/lib/` and `/bin/` and your "root directory" `/` which all of these are under.

Your personal files, like data, text, pictures, and others are under your `/home/` directory and are under what we refer to as your "user's home directory" which would be `/home/codinggirl/` if your user name were "codinggirl" for example.

However, there are some system files under your user's home directory as well and these are usually hidden files and directories that start with a dot, like `/home/codinggirl/.config` for example, which contain configuration files for your personal settings.

Additionally, it should be noted that the "tilde" `~` symbol can be substituted for `/home/codinggirl` so that `~/.config/` is the same as `/home/codinggirl/.config/` and `~/` is the same as `/home/codinggirl/`.

To print (show) your current working directory, run the following command:

```
pwd
```

To list the files in your current directory, run the following command:

```
ls
```

To list the files in your current directory and to also list hidden files and directories, run the following command:

```
ls -a
```

To change to a different directory, you can use the `cd` command. For example, if you are currently in your user's home directory, you could use the following command to change to your Downloads directory:

```
cd Downloads
```

Alternatively, the following command will do the same thing by listing the full path to the directory:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

However, to go back one directory, you can use two dots before a forwardslash like this:

```
cd ../
```

and if you run the `cd` command with no argument, it will take you back to your user's home directory:

```
cd
```

Also, the current directory is always represented by a dot before a forward slash `./`

So, another way to change to your Downloads directory from your user's home directory would be to use the following:

```
cd ./Downloads
```

or

```
cd /home/codinggirl/Downloads
```

and to go back to your user's home directory, from your Downloads directory, you could use

```
cd ../
```

or

```
cd
```

or

```
cd ~/
```

---

Partitions are usually "mounted" to a directory so, unlike Windows, the partition will be listed under the directory name (folder name) it is mounted to instead of listed as a partition or drive like "drive C:" as it is in Windows.

For example, if Ubuntu is installed under a single partition, your equivalent of a "c: drive" on Ubuntu would simply be `/`

For another example, you could also have a separate partition or drive mounted to `/home/`. If you have another partition or drive mounted to `/home/`, that partition or drive would simply be under `/home/`.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you mean with "normal files"

user files are normally stored in the home directory of the user

each "normal user" has a home directory : normally  that's /home/userid folder and the user can store his/her files and subdirectories there

Comment: does it have relation with partition and directories?

Comment: it can be linked to partitioning as it's possible to choose a particular partition for the /home directory : some more info here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes